# How to find the Port ID in Biztalk 2010?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have configured a receiving port named it "SalesOrder" It contains a receiving location of File Type.

Now when i use this receiving port in a Send port i define a filter like this :

```
BTS.ReceivePortName==SalesOrder
```

I start the ports and it works just fine.

Now question is if i want to us the filter like this :

```
BTS.ReceivePortID=="Where do i get the Port ID"
```

How can i find the PortID in Biztalk 2010.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't an easy way of getting to the ReceivePortID. The id will also change when creating, deleting, setting up new port and of course as you move you configuration between environments. It's much more common practice to set up these kind of filter based on ReceivePortName instead as this (hopefully) doesn't change as much.

Best practice in my opinion is however to not use these kind of filters that are tied to the configuration but to rather set up filters based on message types and order other promoted properties. Using promoted properties over configuration will also create a more flexible and more loosely coupled solution.

Comment: I did some digging into the Biztalk [BizTalkMgmtDb] and found a table called [bts_receiveport] which is where all the Recive ports details are stored and we can find the ID from here.